# Bivariate continuous density function: How is it possible to define conditional density?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Maybe this is a very trivial question for an experienced mathematician, but it is something mysterious for someone from an engineering background, like me; this is bugging me for a long time:

Let's define a bivariate, continuous distribution $p_{x,y}(x,y)$ which is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p_{x,y}(x,y)dxdy = 1$. We can define a conditional density which for example is $p_{x|y}(x|y=Y)$ in this setting. The definition of conditional probability is: $p_{x|y}(x|y=Y) = \frac{p_{x,y}(x,y=Y)}{p_{y}(y=Y)}$. Now, something which confuses me is that: $p_y$ is a continuous density function,too and by definition it must be $p_{y}(y=Y) = 0$ since $\int_{Y}^{Y}p_{y}(y)dy = 0$. So this must make the conditional density function $p_{x|y}$ undefined. But this is clearly not the case. How is this contradiction resolved?

Thanks is advance.

Comment: It sounds like you're mixing up densities and probabilities. The probability $y = Y$ is zero, but the density at $y = Y$ need not be zero. Think of a density like a Gaussian. Is it identically zero?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am aware of the distinction, but if we  have the conditional density $p_{x|y}$ and its closed form analytic formula, like a Gaussian as you said, we can calculate for example $\int_{-\infty}^{X}p_{x|y}(x|y=Y)dx$. Now, this is the definition of a cumulative density and it has to give a probability value in the range $[0,1]$. But we calculate this conditioned on $y=Y$, a zero-probability event. How is this possible?

Comment: You wrote that $p_y(y=Y) = 0$ since $\int_{Y}^{Y}p_y(y)\operatorname{d}y = 0$. The former is the density evaluated at $y = Y$ and the the integral gives the probability that $y = Y$. As I said before, these are not the same.

Comment: I think there is a confusion because of the notation I have used. $f_{x,y}(x,y)$ is the joint density function. $f_{x|y}(x)$ is the conditional density function. What I am saying is, with more correct notation, the probability that $P(x < X|y=Y)$ is not defined, which is $\int_{-\infty}^X\int_{Y}^{Y}f_{x,y}(x,y)dxdy / \int_{Y}^{Y}f_{x,y}(x,y)dy = P(x<X,y=Y)/P(y=Y)$

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2284924/intuitive-explanation-of-conditional-density-function/2285130#2285130) for some intuition.

Answer (score 0):

We want to define $p_{X|Y=b}$ such that 
$$ X|Y=b \sim p_{X|Y=b} $$
in the same way that is understood
$$ Z \sim p_Z $$
when $Z$ is random variable.

Let $ x\in \mathbb{R}$, you can think that the probability of $X|Y=b$ belongs to a small interval centered on $x$ is directly proportional to $p(x,b)$. This suggests defining
$$ p_{X|Y=b}(x) = \frac{p_{X,Y}(x,b)}{p_Y(b)} $$
when $p_Y(b) \neq 0$.

In fact, this is enough to give a good definition of $ p_{X|Y=b}$ (since that the set of $b$'s where $p_Y(b)=0$ has Lebesgue measure null). In addition, it is easy to verify that 
$$ \mathbb{P}(a_1<X\le a_2|Y=b) = \int_{a_1}^{a_2} p_{X|Y=b}dx $$
and 
$$ \mathbb{E}[X|Y=b] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty xp_{X|Y=b}(x)dx $$
how we wanted.

Answer (score -1):

$$p_Y(y_0) \neq \int_{y_0}^{y_0} p_Y(y)\text{d}y = P(y_0 \leq Y \leq y_0)= P(Y \leq y_0)-P(Y \leq y_0)= 0 \,\,,$$
for $y_0$ in the domain of $Y$ (necessarily).
In other words, it might be the case that $p_Y(y_0)= P(Y=y_0)=0$, but this is not necessarily true. As a matter of fact, it must be the case that $$p_{X,Y}(x,y_0) = P(X=x,Y=y_0) \leq p_Y(y_0) =P(Y=y_0) \,\,\,\text{for any $x \in D_X$}\,,$$
where $D_X$ is the domain of $X$.

Comment: I think there is a confusion because of the notation I have used. $f_{x,y}(x,y)$ is the joint density function. $f_{x|y}(x)$ is the conditional density function. What I am saying is, with more correct notation, the probability that $P(x < X|y=Y)$ is not defined, which is $\int_{-\infty}^X\int_{Y}^{Y}f_{x,y}(x,y)dxdy / \int_{Y}^{Y}f_{x,y}(x,y)dy = P(x<X,y=Y)/P(y=Y)$

Comment: The confusion, for me, is that you are using lower case letters for random variables and upper case letters for constants...unless I am reading what you have written wrong...usually $X,Y$ are used to denote random variables, while $x,y$ are used to denote their values, which are not random but variable. @UfukCanBiçici (although it might be the case that you are writing equalities backwards and following this convention)

Comment: either way, your integration is wrong in the equivalence you have stated...you are confusing the density function with the probability that a random variable equals a fixed constant in its domain...the latter is zero, while the former is not necessarily zero at all.

Comment: "As a matter of fact, it must be the case that $p_{X,Y}(x,y_0) = P(X=x,Y=y_0) \leq p_Y(y_0) =P(Y=y_0)$" As a matter of fact, if $p_{X,Y}$ and $p_Y$ are the densities they are supposed to be, this is often NOT the case. (Let us try to avoid muddying the waters some more with ambiguous statements, shall we?)

Comment: @Did what are you talking about? You think it's more likely that $X=x$ for some $x$ in the domain of $X$ AND $Y=y_0$ than it is for just $Y=y_0$...what you're saying makes no sense

Comment: If this is the case @Did, then the conditional probability would be greater than 1 for some $x$, which isn't possible

Comment: *Proof*. Let $E$ and $F$ be events. Then by one of the probability axioms, it follows that $$P(E \,|\,F) = \frac{P(E \cap F)}{P(F)} \leq 1.$$ Thus, the probability of the intersection of two events is always less than the probability of one of the events in the intersection.

Comment: You are using deductions valid in the discrete case to draw incorrect conclusions in the continuous one. Elementary (counter-)example: $(X,Y)$ uniform on $[0,t]\times[0,1]$ with $t$ in $(0,1)$. Now, it happens that further discussing your basic mistakes with you after you reacted as you did is not my immediate priority, so, if you will excuse me...

Comment: @Did...that proof is valid for any probability, including the continuous case

Comment: Either way, the OP is wrong in what he is saying...the density evaluated at some point in it's domain is not necessarily zero, while the probability of the same random variable with the above density (continous) carrying that same point *is* zero @Did...note that is solely a property of continuous random variables...discrete random variables can carry a single point in their domain with positive probability

Comment: 1- @AlbertSteppi Actually I had to state the question as follows, sorry for the chaos it caused: We have the joint, continuous probability density function $f_{X,Y}(X,Y)$. Now which is confusing for me was thinking about the equation $P(x_0 < X < x_1 |Y=y)=\int_{x_0}^{x_1}f_{X|Y=y}(X)dX$ and saying that how it can  $P(x_0 < X < x_1 |Y=y)$ be defined since $P(Y=y)=0$.

Comment: 2- But if I understand it correctly from the answers the equation $P(x_0 < X < x_1 |Y=y)=\int_{x_0}^{x_1}f_{X|Y=y}(X)dX$ is not correct to begin with. Although $\int_{x_0}^{x_1}f_{X|Y=y}(X)dX$ returns a value in the interval $[0,1]$, this is not a **probability**, it is a ratio of densities $\frac{\int_{x_0}^{x_1}f_{X,Y}(X,Y=y)dX}{f_{Y}(Y)}$. Am I right with that?