# Intuitive explanation of conditional density function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

So conditional density is defined this way $f_{X|Y}\left(x,y\right)=\frac{f_{  X,Y }\left(x,y\right)}{f_Y(y)} $.

I was wondering why it was not simply thus $f_{X|Y}\left(x,y\right)= f_{  X,Y }\left(x,Y=y\right)$. In this function we are taking the slice of the function of two variables along the line Y=y,so what we get looks like a pdf for X when Y =y.

Comment: It's because you must scale the density so that it integrates to $1$. Remember, you are regarding $y$ as a fixed constant.

Comment: Sorry I still don't quite understand how it works.

Comment: Think about what would happen in the case that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Since in that case $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$, you get $f_{X|Y}(x,y)=\frac{f_X(x)f_Y(y)}{f_Y(y)}=f_X(x)$, as expected.

Comment: Two things that might help: One, compare to the corresponding discrete scenario where the joint pmf is laid out on a 2-way table and see that your proposal in that scenario means simply taking any particular row or any particular column to be considered to be a pmf on their own (which cannot be because a row/column would not add to 1). Second, look at a cross-section view of the volume under a surface (e.g., http://www.math.tamu.edu/~tkiffe/calc3/cross_section2/square.html) and notice any such cross-section wouldnt automatically have area 1.

Answer (score 2):

To be a probability density, you want $\displaystyle \int_x f_{X\mid Y=y}(x) \, dx =1$

But $\displaystyle \int_x f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, dx =f_{Y}(y)$ which is usually not $1$; you need to divide by $f_{Y}(y)$ to get a probability density since $\displaystyle\dfrac{1}{f_{Y}(y)} \int_x f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, dx = \int_x \dfrac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_{Y}(y)} \, dx =1$

---

The way I remember this intuitively is to think about this by considering the discrete random variable $X$ taking possible values $x_1,x_2,\ldots$ and similarly the discrete random variable $Y$

Now you have $\mathbb{P}(X=x_i, Y=y_j) = \mathbb{P}(X=x_i \mid Y=y_j)\mathbb{P}(Y_j)$ and so $\mathbb{P}(X=x_i \mid Y=y_j)=\dfrac{\mathbb{P}(X=x_i, Y=y_j)}{\mathbb{P}(Y_j)}= \dfrac{\mathbb{P}(X=x_i, Y=y_j)}{\sum_k\mathbb{P}(X=x_k, Y=y_j)}$ and clearly summing over $i$ gives a result of $1$ as desired

The density result is similar but using integration rather than summation

Answer (score 1):

Heuristically, the conditional density function can be viewed as
\begin{align*}
f_{X|Y}(x\mid y)&=
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0}P(X\le x \mid y \le Y \le y+\delta) \right)\\
&=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0}\frac{P(X\le x,y \le Y \le y+\delta)}{P(y \le Y \le y+\delta)} \right)\\
&=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0}\frac{\int_{-\infty}^x\int_y^{y+\delta} f_{X, Y}(u, v)dudv}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_y^{y+\delta} f_{X, Y}(u, v)dudv} \right)\\
&=\lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0}\frac{\int_y^{y+\delta} f_{X, Y}(x, v)dv}{\int_y^{y+\delta} f_Y(v)dv}\\
&=\frac{f_{X, Y}(x, y)}{f_Y(y)}.
\end{align*}
Noe that this intepretaion is still ad-hoc, as it is possible that $P(y \le Y \le y+\delta)=0$, for certain $\delta>0$.

Formally, note that, the condition density is the function $f_{X|Y}(x\mid y)$ such that, for any Borel set $C$,
\begin{align*}
E(1_{X\in C}\mid Y=y) = \int_C f_{X|Y}(x\mid y) dx.
\end{align*} 
In addition, note that the conditional expectation $$E(1_{X\in C}\mid Y=y)$$ is also a Borel measurable function such that for any Borel set $B$
\begin{align*}
\int_{Y\in B} 1_{X\in C} dP &= \int_{B}E(1_{X\in C}\mid Y=y) P_Y(dy) \\
&= \int_{B}E(1_{X\in C}\mid Y=y) f_Y(y)dy\\
&= \int_{B}\int_C f_{X|Y}(x\mid y)  f_Y(y) dx dy,\tag{1}
\end{align*}
where $P_Y(dy)$ is the measure generated by the distribution function of $Y$. On the other hand,
\begin{align*}
\int_{Y\in B} 1_{X\in C} dP = \int_{B}\int_C f_{X, Y}(x, y) dx dy.\tag{2}
\end{align*}
Comparing $(1)$ and $(2)$, we see that
\begin{align*}
f_{X|Y}(x\mid y) = \frac{f_{X, Y}(x, y)}{f_Y(y)}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the notation $f_{X\mid Y=y}(x)$ rather than $f_{X\mid Y}(x,y)$ because it is a function of only one variable.

I think that what you mean by $f_{X,Y}(x,Y=y)$ is the function $x\mapsto f_{X,Y}(x,y)$. If this is the case, the conditional density is essentially that. Except for the fact that this function is not a density function. Thats is why we have the renormalization $f_{Y}(y)$.